# How to find tangent line on a curve of unknown function?

Tags: graphs

I have x and y values to plot the curve and I need to find a tangent line of slope 1 that intersects the curve and the point at which it intersects. I was trying to do polynomial and exponential regression to model the data (>6000 data points) and fit the curve in R but cannot get it to work. It fits a majority of the data but not the curve and I want the function of the curve to find the derivative and tangent.

I don't completely understand the math behind the modeling but all I know is that the fit is inaccurate when I plot it against my data. Is there any way I solve this mathematically or geometrically? [The curve starts slightly downwards, then slopes up gradually before it goes up exponentially](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38bNs.png)

If you do a density plot, most of the values are towards the lower end of y. [the values of y are right skewed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7Jhm.png). This is probably why my model doesn't fit the curved region, so would one solution be to remove multiple prior points?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Some (x,y) values don't uniquely determine a curve, so you'll have to specify what curve you have in mind.  I don't know what "solve this" means because I'm not sure what the exact specification of the task you're trying to solve is.

Answer (score 1):

If you rotate the plot by a suitable angle that makes the tangent horizontal, your problem is recast as that of finding the minimum of the curve, which is a simple problem. For better accuracy, you can fit a parabola *on a few neighbors* of the lowest point.

[image]

Anyway, notice that your axis have widly varying ranges, so that a slope of 1 is quite dubious. Better check that.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of fitting a curve and then finding the tangent to the fitted curve seems like a sensible approach.

No fitted curve will ever exactly match all of the points.  If you aren't fitting all of the data, then the family of curves doesn't fully model the distribution the data actually came from.  One simple approach is to choose a window of x-values (e.g., 6000...7000) that likely contains the desired point, keep only the data in that window, and fit the best curve you can to that data.